# com.mongodb.MongoException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionException: Command failed with error 251 (NoSuchTransaction):

Tags: mongodb, transactions, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux, spring-transactions

I have next code

```
public void updateComics(ReceiverRecord<String, UpdateTask> record) {

  UpdateTask task = record.value();

  List<PageMD> pageList = task.getPages().stream().map(PageMD::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
  Comics comic = task.getComics();
  PageMD lastPage = Iterables.getLast(pageList);
  comic.setLastUpdate(LocalDateTime.now());
  comic.setPageCount(lastPage.getNumber());

  transactionalOperator.execute(status -> pageRepos.saveAll(pageList)
           .doOnNext(page -> logger.info("page save = {} ", page))
           .doOnError(err -> logger.error("Error saving page ", err))
           .then(comicsRepos.save(new ComicsMD(comic)))
           .doOnNext(com -> logger.info("comic save = {}", com))
           .doOnError(com -> {
                    logger.error("error saving comic ", com);
                    status.setRollbackOnly();
            }))
           .doOnError(error -> logger.error("An error happen while execute transaction = ", error))
           .subscribe();
}
```

And I have error when I save data (pages) in mongodb

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionException: 
Command failed with error 251 (NoSuchTransaction): 'Given transactionnumber 1 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is -1' on server mongo:27017. 
The full response is {"errorLabels": ["TransientTransactionError"], "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1587986663, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Given transaction number 1 does not match any in-progress transactions. 
The active transaction number is -1", "code": 251, "codeName": "NoSuchTransaction", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1587986663, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type": "00"}, "keyId": {"$numberLong": "0"}}}}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 251 (NoSuchTransaction): 'Given transaction number 1 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is -1' on server mongo:27017. The full response is {"errorLabels": ["TransientTransactionError"], "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1587986663, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Given transaction number 1 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is -1", "code": 251, "codeName": "NoSuchTransaction", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1587986663, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type": "00"}, "keyId": {"$numberLong": "0"}}}}
parsers-manager            |   
 at com.mongodb.MongoException.fromThrowableNonNull(MongoException.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar!/:na]
```

Whithout reactive transaction it is work. How can I fix this?

Comment: you should not call `subscribe()` in your application and reactive application don't have void methods. And also we dont have the full context. How is this called, how is the repositories setup, how is mongo configured. etc etc. You dont need the `transactionalOperator`, if you are using spring repositories. It is onsly used if you are doing custom requests https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/16/reactive-transactions-with-spring

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-reactive#2-reactivemongorepository

Comment: This is strange because a comparable piece of code works for me well. Those errors can occur when you execute queries within transaction in parallel but from what I can see in your code snippet this does not happen here. I assume you have no custom implementation of `saveAll()` and `save()` methods where the problem could appear. If not then try to update mongo driver to the latest version if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar error in one of our projects. After spending a lot of time we came to this hypothesis. For the Spring Mongo transaction, the actual transaction is started when the first request is sent to the database. It does not matter what kind of request - find, query, update, save etc. So, when the first request is sent in parallel with any other requests, but was not able to complete before them, and they think that the transaction has been started (but it hasn't), then we see this error occur. "The transaction x+1 does not exist. Last transaction is x".

To fix this error, we made changes to our flow so that when the first request is made to MongoDB, there are no parallel DB calls.

In your case, in the **saveAll** method there are any parallel calls made to the DB and that might be causing this error.